# Accounting for Complex Types & Properties in Microsoft.AspNet.OData

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, odata

I am having trouble getting a complex object to serialize.  I have found few examples on this & need some help.  I have a POCO class that implements an Interface for a Class Property, as below...

- The problem is...OData cannot serialize the **IObjectState** Property

**HOW DO I MAKE ODATA AWARE of COMPLEX TYPES IN PROPERTIES?**

- Please keep in mind the IObjectState is a non-entity class & has no key

**POCO CLASS:**

```
public class ShakeoutDocument : Document, IDocument, IStateful
{
    public IObjectState ObjectState { get; set; } //<-- This property contains the instance (below)

    public int ShakeoutId { get; set; }

    public string SchedulingBatch { get; set; }

    [...] //<-- Other properties are omitted for brevity
}
```

**IObjectState Property CLASS:**
Here is an example of a concrete IObjectState class...

```
// Example of an IObjectState Instance
public class New : IObjectState
{
    public List<IObjectStateEvent> Events { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

**EDM CONFIGURATION: As a BOUND Function:**
Using this EDM Model configuration & Api...

```
modelBuilder.EntitySet<ShakeoutDocument>("ShakeoutDocument");

[HttpGet]
public ShakeoutDocument Get([FromODataUri] int id)
{
    var provider = Application.ShakeoutDocumentProvider as ShakeoutDocumentProvider;
    var entity = provider.Get(id);

    return entity;
}
```

Generates the following exception...

> "The given model does not contain the type 'New'."

**EDM CONFIGURATION: As a UNBOUND Function:**
Using this EDM Model configuration & Api...

```
var getShakeoutDocument = modelBuilder.Function("GetShakeoutDocument").ReturnsFromEntitySet<ShakeoutDocument>("ShakeoutDocument");
getShakeoutDocument.Parameter<int>("id");

[ODataRoute("GetShakeoutDocument(id={id})")]
public IHttpActionResult GetShakeoutDocument([FromODataUri] int id)
{
    var provider = Application.ShakeoutDocumentProvider as ShakeoutDocumentProvider;
    var entity = provider.Get(id);

    return Ok(entity);
}
```

Generates the following exception...

> "The given model does not contain the type 'New'."

**UPDATING THE EDM CONFIGURATION: with concrete New:**
Updating the EDM Model configuration with...

```
modelBuilder.AddComplexType(typeof(New));
```

Generates the following exception...

> "A value was encountered that has a type name that is incompatible
>   with the metadata. The value specified its type as 'New', but the type
>   specified in the metadata is 'IObjectState'."

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, after much searching, I found the answer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-v4/complex-type-inheritance-in-odata-v4).  Basically, you have to describe to OData all the possible implementations of any given Complex Property...even for UNBOUND FUNCTIONS.

Unbound really *SHOULD* imply standard WebApi is being used...but this obviously isn't the case....as this object serializes FINE using standard WebApi, but fails using OData.

```
private static  IEdmModel GetEdmModel()
{
    var modelBuilder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();

    // ENTITY SETS: Normal
    modelBuilder.EntitySet<tblDbcCommunications>("Communication");
    modelBuilder.EntitySet<tblDbcItems>("Item");
    modelBuilder.EntitySet<Meter>("Meter");
    modelBuilder.EntitySet<Product>("Product");
    modelBuilder.EntitySet<WarehouseMeter>("WarehouseMeter");
    modelBuilder.EntitySet<Shakeout>("Shakeout");
    modelBuilder.EntitySet<tblDbcCircuitOwner>("tblDbcCircuitOwner");

    // ENTITY SETS: Complex
    ConfigureComplexEntitySet(modelBuilder, modelBuilder.EntitySet<ShakeoutDocument>("ShakeoutDocument"));

    // KEY BINDINGS
    modelBuilder.EntityType<WarehouseMeter>().HasKey(x => x.METER_ID);

    // UNBOUND FUNCTIONS
    //  - Action    = Post
    //  - Function  = Get

    // WarehouseMeter
    var findPulseMeter = modelBuilder.Function("FindWarehouseMeter").ReturnsCollectionFromEntitySet<WarehouseMeter>("WarehouseMeter");
    findPulseMeter.Parameter<string>("search");

    // ShakeoutDocument
    var getShakeoutDocument = modelBuilder.Function("GetShakeoutDocument").ReturnsFromEntitySet<ShakeoutDocument>("ShakeoutDocument");
    getShakeoutDocument.Parameter<int>("id");

    // Product
    var listProduct = modelBuilder.Function("ListProducts").ReturnsCollectionFromEntitySet<Product>("Product");

    return modelBuilder.GetEdmModel();
}

private static EntitySetConfiguration<ShakeoutDocument> ConfigureComplexEntitySet(ODataConventionModelBuilder modelBuilder, EntitySetConfiguration<ShakeoutDocument> configuration)
{

    // Collection Properties
    configuration.EntityType.CollectionProperty(x => x.Seals);
    configuration.EntityType.CollectionProperty(x => x.Details);

    // Complex Properties
    configuration.EntityType.ComplexProperty(x => x.ObjectState);

    // Object State
    var newObjectState = modelBuilder.ComplexType<New>();
    newObjectState.DerivesFrom<IObjectState>();

    var submittedObjectState = modelBuilder.ComplexType<Submitted>();
    submittedObjectState.DerivesFrom<IObjectState>();

    // Object State Event
    var isNewObjectStateEvent = modelBuilder.ComplexType<IsNew>();
    isNewObjectStateEvent.DerivesFrom<IObjectStateEvent>();

    var isSubmittedObjectStateEvent = modelBuilder.ComplexType<IsSubmitted>();
    isSubmittedObjectStateEvent.DerivesFrom<IObjectStateEvent>();

    return configuration;
}
```